# Как сохранять и загружать данные в/из кэша при повторном запуске приложения на Android?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, кэширование

Есть полезные ссылки на данную тему? Я так понимаю, что мне нужно будет создать БД на SQlite в приложении, занести туда данные. А вот как дальше действовать? Как мне их отобразить из кэша, а не заново "скачивать"?

Comment: Что за данные, почему их надо кэшировать ? Чем более подробно и точно вы опишите свою проблему, а так же шаги, уже предпринятые вами для ее решения, тем больше вероятность получить на нее полезный ответ. В таком виде ваш вопрос тянет только на закрытие

Comment: JSON-данные. Потому что это оптимизирует приложение и пользователю не придется ждать их загрузки в n-ый раз. Сейчас у меня есть эти данные в понятном всем виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вопроса не ясно какой объем данных (переменных, массивов) необходимо сохранять при выходе из приложения?!

Если данных немного, то можно воспользоваться механизмом: "SharedPreferences":

Назначение переменных для сохранения:

```
static final String SAVE_USERID = "save_userid";
static final String SAVE_PASSWORD = "save_password";
public static String un = "MyName", pw = "MyPassword";
```

Метод сохранения:

```
public void saveSettings() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("setting",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    ed.putString(SAVE_USERID, un);
    ed.putString(SAVE_PASSWORD, pw);
    ed.commit();
}
```

Медод восстановления:

```
public void loadSettings() {
    un = getSharedPreferences("setting",MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SAVE_USERID, "");
    pw = getSharedPreferences("setting",MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SAVE_PASSWORD, "");
}
```

Если данных много, то необходима работа с БД.

Comment: Все же хранить именно пароли таким образом не стоит. Так он никак не защищен от нехороших людей, так как преференсы хранятся в явном виде в обычном текстовом файле. Как минимум, перед сохранением его надо зашифровать, а при получении - расшифровать.

Comment: Пароль я привел для примера. Согласен, если необходимо шифровать данные, то их надо шифровать. Все зависит от поставленной задачи!

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите на Firebase, там реализованы БД для NoSQL (для сохранения структурированных данных типа JSON) и реализовано кеширование, а так же много других полезных фич

Comment: 3 года 1 месяц назад был задан вопрос  
Потерял актуальность, по крайне мере для меня